# Android Wear on Samsung Galaxy Gear Live

Tags: stock-android

I want to get a Samsung Galaxy Gear Live,and want to use it on its own gsm network,is this possible? Also,does this watch support data through  wifi connection?

Answer (score 1):

Gear Live doesn't even have a SIM slot, so how would you expect GSM?

It does have limited WiFi capabilities which are enabled in an [earlier update](http://www.droid-life.com/2015/05/19/these-are-the-android-wear-watches-getting-wifi-support/) to Android Wear.